# Spring app with Docker fails on startup with class path error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

Just started a bare bones project and when trying to run up a Docker container with a simple index page, using the mvn spring-boot:build-image command for building, I get the following error.

Not sure if this is a Tomcat or Spring issue? Only found one similar problem here on SO and that was related to a mix of incompatible versions but in this case I am pretty sure all of the pom is up to date. I also tried a build without Undertow but same response.

Have not been able to find any similar issues on the Net. Also, noting that it runs just fine when starting from within Intellij, only fails when dockerized.

```
silenceisgrand   |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
silenceisgrand   | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
silenceisgrand   |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
silenceisgrand   |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
silenceisgrand   |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
silenceisgrand   |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.2.RELEASE)
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | 2020-11-09 09:01:15,366 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Starting SilenceisgrandApplication v0.0.1 on fd30e9598f54 with PID 1 (/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes started by cnb in /workspace)
silenceisgrand   | 2020-11-09 09:01:15,367 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: The following profiles are active: h2o
silenceisgrand   | 2020-11-09 09:01:15,723 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate: Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
silenceisgrand   | 2020-11-09 09:01:15,758 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate: Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 29ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
silenceisgrand   | 2020-11-09 09:01:16,037 WARN  [main] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.coyote.ProtocolHandler org.apache.coyote.ProtocolHandler.create(java.lang.String, boolean)'
silenceisgrand   | 2020-11-09 09:01:16,044 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener: 
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
silenceisgrand   | 2020-11-09 09:01:16,045 ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter: 
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | ***************************
silenceisgrand   | APPLICATION FAILED TO START
silenceisgrand   | ***************************
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | Description:
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   |     org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:87)
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | The following method did not exist:
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   |     'org.apache.coyote.ProtocolHandler org.apache.coyote.ProtocolHandler.create(java.lang.String, boolean)'
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | The method's class, org.apache.coyote.ProtocolHandler, is available from the following locations:
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   |     jar:file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-coyote-10.0.0-M8.jar!/org/apache/coyote/ProtocolHandler.class
silenceisgrand   |     jar:file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/org/apache/coyote/ProtocolHandler.class
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   |     org.apache.coyote.ProtocolHandler: file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-coyote-10.0.0-M8.jar
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | Action:
silenceisgrand   | 
silenceisgrand   | Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.coyote.ProtocolHandler
```

And the pom looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.silenceisgrand</groupId>
    <artifactId>silenceisgrand</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>silenceisgrand</name>
    <description>The core silenceisgrand.com site</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>4.5.3</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Undertow; replacing Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- webjars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hamcrest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf java8time extras -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You are mixing different versions of spring boot/spring...

Comment: Not sure where I mix versions? Setting setting Undertow to 2.3.2 or even removing it does not change anything... Sorry, confused

Comment: You are using spring-boot-starter-undertow:2.3.4.RELEASE but your parent is version 2.3.2.RELEASE furthermore you are defining spring-security-test with version 5.4.0. I strongly recommend to use the versions defined by the spring-boot parent instead and not overwriting the versions. Also move to the most recent versions of [spring-boot-parent 2.3.5.RELEASE](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent) ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you very much! I did indeed not realise that the parent version was lower than Undertow. I took away all local version tags relating to spring boot, cleaned the maven project, deleted caches and re-built the project. Now it works correctly. It is obvious I have to read up on the parent-child relation of maven poms. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that I mixed up the versions, maven was messing with me and refusing a version 2.3.5.RELEASE saying there is no such version. In the end I had to first clean the project, then to delete Intellij caches upon which maven was happy and after rebuilding the image it now behaves all well.